# TypeScript get object nested in JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an object JSON :

```
"product": [
  {
    "code": "A",
    "value": "A",
    "id": 1,
    "subproduct": [
       { "name": "C", "id": 31 },
       { "name": "S", "id": 32 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like get the subproduct with the ID product
The JSON is get by a service
I try the code below :

```
let result = this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(
   map((x) => x.product),
   filter((y) => y.id === 1)
);
```

*** UPDATE ***

If i try the code,  I have the code = "A"

```
this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(map((x) => x.product.filter((x) => x.id === 1)));
```

But It's doesn't work, Why I can't get the nested object "subproduct"

If i write

```
return this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(map((x) => x.product.subproduct.filter((x) => x.id === 1)));
```

I have this error

```
ERROR TypeError: "x.product.subproduct is undefined"
```

**RESULT EXPECTED**

below the result expected, I need just the subproduct

```
[
  { "name": "C", "id": 31 },
  { "name": "S", "id": 32 }
]
```

Thank for your help

Comment: "It's [sic] doesn't work" is not a great problem description. Please tell us what error you receive, or what result you get that you didn't expect. Note that nowhere in your code is the name `subproduct` mentioned, so why would it be part of the result?

Comment: @HereticMonkey; I edited the post... thank for your help

Comment: You're close: `return this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(map((x) => x.product.filter((x) => x.id === 1).subproduct));` The important thing is to remember where you are in the hierarchy

Comment: @HereticMonkey  the return is "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Hope it will work!.

```
const product = [
      {
          "code": "A",
          "value": "A",
          "id": 1,
          "subproduct": [
               { "name": "C", "id": 31 },
               { "name": "S", "id": 32 }
          ]
      }
    ];
    const results = product.find(item => item.id === 1).subproduct;
    console.log(results);
```

Comment: This is close to the answer, but needs to deal with the fact that the OP is using `Observable`s.

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe an `Observable` through `filter` operator - you are actually filtering the emissions of that `Observable`. To work with actual values that `Observable` emits - you need to put all the transformations inside the `map` operator.

```
let result = this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(
   map((data) => {
     return data.product.find((p) => p.id === your_id)
   }),
);
```

Comment: I try  this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(
                  map((data) => {
                    return data.product.subproduct.find((p) => p.id === 10);
                  })
                );  but I had this message ERROR TypeError: "data.product.subproduct is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `result` observable stream with desired output and subscribe to it.

```
let result = this.dataService.getJSON().pipe(
  pluck('product'),
  map(products => {
    const product = products.find(eachProduct => eachProduct.id === 1);
    return product && product.subproduct;
  }),
);
```

Now you can subscribe to `result` observable to get `subproduct` array

```
result.subscribe(subproduct => {
  // You have access to subproduct array here.

  console.log(subproduct)
})
```

If product with `id` is not found, you'll get `undefined` subproduct in subscription assuming subproduct always exist for a given product.